# TCP Socket Servers

Tags: python, tcpserver, socketserver

Is even possible to start multiple TCP socket server using an list? Maybe a sample would be more useful

```
class MyHttpRequestHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
   #This is my handler. It works great for one server so not including it to save space

handler_object = MyHttpRequestHandler
my_servers = []
PORT = 8080
for dev in devices:
   my_servers.append(socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), handler_object))
   PORT += 1

for server in my_servers:
   server.serve_forever()
```

So basically what I want to do is iterate through the `my_servers` list and start each of the servers. IK there may be a chance of starting too many servers, but the function that populates `devices` takes care of that.